# Selecting the last 5 posts from topics?

Tags: php, mysql, posts

Hi am trying to select last five topics that posts was made.
The query i have i thought would have worked but am really stuck on this one if anyone can help me out please.
 
    `$query = yasDB_select("SELECT * FROM forumposts INNER JOIN forumtopics ON forumposts.id=forumtopics.id ORDER by forumposts.date DESC limit 5");`

Comment: Order by the date, in descending order.

Comment: please add example data and expected output

Comment: http://www.games-flash.co.uk/forumcats/1/1.html if you go here you can see my latest post output.I tried your query bulk but no joy.

Comment: the last post was made on March 17, 2015, 9:53 pm so that one should show at top of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognised a few problems with your query.

Proper solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(forumtopics.name)
FROM forumtopics LEFT JOIN forumposts ON forumposts.topicid = forumtopics.id
ORDER BY forumposts.id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

If you are interested in more complex data about topics you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(forumtopics.id) FROM forumtopics LEFT
JOIN forumposts  ON forumposts.topicid = forumtopics.id ) topics  LEFT
JOIN forumtopics ON topics.id = forumtopics.id ORDER BY topics.id DESC
LIMIT 5 ;
```

I used the following test schema:

```
CREATE TABLE forumposts (   id int,   topicid int,   content text ); 
CREATE TABLE forumtopics (   id int,   name varchar(200) );
INSERT INTO forumtopics SET id = 1, name = "1st topic"; INSERT INTO
forumtopics SET id = 2, name = "2nd topic"; INSERT INTO forumtopics
SET id = 3, name = "3rd topic"; INSERT INTO forumtopics SET id = 4,
name = "4th topic"; INSERT INTO forumtopics SET id = 5, name = "5th
topic"; INSERT INTO forumtopics SET id = 6, name = "6th topic";

INSERT INTO forumposts SET id = 1, topicid=1, content = "1st post";
INSERT INTO forumposts SET id = 2, topicid=3, content = "2nd post";
INSERT INTO forumposts SET id = 3, topicid=3, content = "3rd post";
INSERT INTO forumposts SET id = 4, topicid=4, content = "4th post";
INSERT INTO forumposts SET id = 5, topicid=5, content = "5th post";
INSERT INTO forumposts SET id = 6, topicid=6, content = "6th post";
INSERT INTO forumposts SET id = 7, topicid=6, content = "7th post";
```

You can test the queries on http://sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Thanks guys i got it working on localhost but can't get it to work on my server.I think there is something wrong with my server so am looking into it.<code>$query = yasDB_select("SELECT forumtopics.id, forumtopics.subject, forumposts.date, forumposts.name FROM forumtopics INNER JOIN forumposts ON forumposts.topic = forumtopics.id ORDER BY forumposts.date DESC LIMIT 5");</code> that query works well on localhost.